# Random number between negative and positive value

Tags: javascript, random, numbers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Generating random numbers in Javascript in a specific range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527803/generating-random-numbers-in-javascript-in-a-specific-range)

How can i get a random value between, for example,  from -99 to 99, excluding 0?

Comment: Get a typical range, subtract the negative amount, see if the number is `0`.

Comment: if zero, call the function again...

Comment: It seems people who voted to close didn't bother to reach word "excluding".

Answer (score 63, accepted):

```
var num = Math.floor(Math.random()*99) + 1; // this will get a number between 1 and 99;
num *= Math.round(Math.random()) ? 1 : -1; // this will add minus sign in 50% of cases
```

---

Altogether

```
var ranNum = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 99) * (Math.round(Math.random()) ? 1 : -1)
```

Comment: I am new to javascript. what is num * here. I mean what is the concept called so that I can learn about it. @LittleSweetSeas

Comment: @DeepikaRao it is a simple multiplication, between a random number (from 0 to 0.999...)  and the target number (99 in our example)

Comment: should be '===' rather than '==' on the second line

Comment: @YikSanChan I may agree, but as the types are well known (both are integers), there would be no real advantages, nor performance gain. Am I wrong? :)

Answer (score 8):

This returns what you want

```
function getNonZeroRandomNumber(){
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*199) - 99;
    if(random==0) return getNonZeroRandomNumber();
    return random;
}
```

Here's a functional [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brunovieira/mb26C/)

## EDIT

To contribute for future readers with a little debate happened in the comments which the user @MarkDickinson made a indeed relevant contribution to my first code posted, I've decided to make another fiddle with a fast comparison between using `Math.floor()` and `Math.round()` functions to return the value the op wanted.

**First Scenario**: Using `var random = Math.round(Math.random()*198) - 99;` (My first suggestion)

```
function getNonZeroRandomNumberWithMathRound(){
    var random = Math.round(Math.random()*198) - 99;
    if(random==0) return getNonZeroRandomNumber();
    return random;
}
```

**Second scenario**: Using `var random=Math.floor(Math.random()*199) - 99;` (Mark suggestion)

```
function getNonZeroRandomNumberWithMathFloor(){
    var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*199) - 99;
    if(random==0) return getNonZeroRandomNumber();
    return random;
}
```

**Methodology**

Since it's a short debate I've chosen [fiddle.net](http://fiddle.net) to do the comparison.

The test consists of running the above functions 100.000 times and then retrieving how much times the extreme numbers `99` and `-99` would appear against a other number, let's say `33` and `-33`.

The test will then give a simple output consisting of the percentage of appearances from `99` and `-99` and the percentage of appearances of `33` and `-33`.

It'll be used the Webkit implementation from `Safari 6.0.2` to the give the output from this answer but anyone can test with your favourite browser late on [fiddle.net](http://fiddle.net)

**Result from first scenario:**

- Percentage of normal ocurrences:0.97%
- Percentage of extreme ocurrences:0.52%
- Percentage of extreme ocurrences relative to normal ocurrences:53.4% // Half the chances indeed

**Result from second scenario:**

- Percentage of normal ocurrences:1.052%
- Percentage of extreme ocurrences:0.974%
- Percentage of extreme ocurrences relative to normal ocurrences:92% //Closer of a fair result with a minimal standard deviation

The result can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/brunovieira/LrXqh/

Comment: I think you want `199` rather than `188`.

Comment: I think I want 198! Just a typo!

Comment: No, you need `199` if you want to include both `-99` and `99` as possibilities.  If you use `198` then there's no way for `99` to come up (at least, not with any reasonable probability).

Comment: I did mean 198 in my answer, but you are right that it wouldn't never return 99. So I'll change from `Math.floor` to `Math.round()`, which will solve the problem. Thanks for noticing by the way

Comment: Aargh!  But with `Math.round`, `-99` and `99` are half as likely to appear as the other values!  (Test it if you don't believe me :-)  You really  *do* want `199` and `Math.floor`!

Comment: I'm testing in this right moment, I'll update the fiddle and the answer with the statistics I found

Comment: Yes, you are right. I'll just update my answer to use Math.floor and 199. Thanks by the way, living and learning

Comment: @MarkDickinson Now I've tested and posted the results. Thanks again

Comment: Please don't suggest this. Even with such lax constraint as 1 number vs. 199, your function have non-zero chance to cause stack overflow. Generally people who get into mindset "reroll random if it doesn't match constraint" will sooner or later will be hit hard with numerous excessive recomputations if constraints are sufficiently tight.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a generalized solution that will let you set the boundaries, and opt in/out of including the `0`.

```
var pos = 99,
    neg = 99,
    includeZero = false,
    result;

do result = Math.ceil(Math.random() * (pos + neg)) - neg;
while (includeZero === false && result === 0);
```

The `pos` and `neg` values are inclusive.

This way there's no requirement that the positive and negative ranges be balanced.

---

Or if you're worried about the rerun due to a single excluded value, you can just make the initial range less by one, and add `1` to any result greater than or equal to `0`.

```
var pos = 5,
    neg = 5,
    result;

result = Math.floor(Math.random() * (pos + neg)) - neg;
result = result < 0 ? result : result + 1;
```

---

That last line could be shorter if you prefer:

```
result += (result >= 0)
```

Comment: `pos = 1 neg = 1`. Can you predict how many cycles it will waste rerolling? Now imagine that "gap" is wider than "correct result".

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov: As is often the case, this is not the right solution for every problem. But it's easy enough to tweak for a narrow range. Of course for a `-1` to `1` range excluding the `0`, we would just do `Math.random() < .5 : -1 : 1;`

Comment: so you need to be aware of whether the number you are passing is positive or negative, rather than just any range? (neg - neg or pos - pos)