# in javascript what is the * after variable name

Tags: javascript, random

I am new to javascript and I am trying to get random positive and negative numbers between 1000 and -1000

There was a reply for it in [How to get Random number + & -](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13455042/random-number-between-negative-and-positive-value)

Here the below suggesion was mentioned

```
var num = Math.floor(Math.random()*99) + 1; // this will get a number between 1 and 99;
num *= Math.floor(Math.random()*2) == 1 ? 1 : -1; // this will add minus sign in 50% of cases
```

What is num *? I mean what is this concept called for me to study more on.

Comment: Shortcut for `num = num * anotherNum`

Comment: `num *= expr` sort for `num = num * expr` (this is javascript 101) - you may also see `-=` `+=` `/=` `%=` and more - all [documented here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators)

Comment: Search for `JavaScript Assignment Operators`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*=` operator is a shorthand for "multiply by", and the following statements are identical:

```
x *= 2;
x = x * 2;
```

As for your actual requirement, here's a simple solution:

```
x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2001) - 1000;
```

Answer (score 1):

This will assign to the `num` variable the result of `num * result of the right side of expression`

`num *= Math.floor(Math.random()*2) == 1 ? 1 : -1`

is just a concise form of writing this

`num = num * Math.floor(Math.random()*2) == 1 ? 1 : -1`

Answer (score 1):

The assignment operator `'='` can also be written as

```
/=
+=
-=
%=
*=
```

and they all stand for

```
x = x / (right hand side);
x = x + (right hand side);
x = x - (right hand side);
x = x % (right hand side);
x = x * (right hand side);
```

Answer (score 1):

If there is a binary arithematic operator before the assignment operator like this

```
a += b
a -= b
a *= b
a /= b
```

It means

```
a = a + b
a = a - b
a = a * b
a = a / b
```

respectively.